# Model bind empty string for DateTime to null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm messing about with the html5 date input field.

```
<input type="date" >
```

I noticed that when you clear the field the value is set to an empty string. So when you post this value to your backend (ASP.NET MVC) the model binder gives a "*String was not recognized as a valid DateTime*" instead of just setting it to `null`.

So I was wondering what the easiest way to tell the model binder that when the field type is DateTime an empty string should be parsed to null.

Model example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

Ctrl example:

```
public void Post(MyModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), it can't hold null. You can use [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) struct (`DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`) to hold null values.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Nullable<DateTime> MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Haha, woops. I just assumed since it's an object :). Hold on let me test with nullable.

Comment: This is one of many reasons to use view models. If your `MyDate` property on your database-persisted entity needs to be not null, you can still make the property on your view model nullable, and then just find some way to recover if it is null, when you try to set `MyDate` on the entity.

Comment: Okay just tested. DateTime? still generates an error.

Comment: @Snæbjørn, the error is due to MVC handling mapping of `date` type to `DateTime` in .Net, I am not an expert in MVC, but you can't hold null in a non-nullable `DateTime`. So my answer , actually answers half part of your question, I will leave it here, until you get some working new answer.